# How to use the bearer token in postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I'm learning jwt authentication with springboot , i'm having problems testing my endpoints

- A sign in request is supposed to create a bearer access token on a successful signin
- Then use the token to access the restricted resources based on the authority
- In postman i've gone to auth tab and selected bearer token and input the token and on headers tab i've entered 'Authorization' on the key input and the token on value input
- When i send a GET request i get the 401 Unauthorized error

My SignIn request

```
{
"username": "patty",
"password": "123456"
 }
```

My response after signin

```
{
"id": 1,
"username": "patty",
"email": "pat@gmail.com",
"roles": [
    "ROLE_USER",
    "ROLE_ADMIN"
 ],
"tokenType": "Bearer",
"accessToken": "the geneated access token" 

 }
```

Logs from the server say `invalid JWT signature: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.`

jwtUtils

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

  @Value("${bezkoder.app.jwtSecret}")
  private String jwtSecret;

  @Value("${bezkoder.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
  private int jwtExpirationMs;

  public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

    UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
        .compact();
  }

  public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
  }

  public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
    try {
      Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
      return true;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
      logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

AuthTokenFilterClass

```
  public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
      @Autowired
      private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    
      @Autowired
      private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
      private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);
    
      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
          String jwt = parseJwt(request);
          if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
            String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
    
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
    
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }
    
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    
      private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    
        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
          return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }
    
        return null;
      }
    }
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    // securedEnabled = true,
    // jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
  @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
  }


  
  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
       
      authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   
      return authProvider;
  }


  
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }


  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Can someone help please,

Here's the repo Credits to Bezkoder https://github.com/bezkoder/spring-boot-security-postgresql.git

Answer (score 0):

Try this method (do not use Bearer from Auth Tab, leave at Default setting).

Create a new `GET` request with your api address.
Within the `Headers` tab, add the following:

- KEY: `Authorization`
- VALUE: `Bearer <accessToken>`

For example:
[image: example of postman GET request with Bearer token]

Comment: i've tried this but still getting the same error